# UML: guideline for visibility

Tags: uml

I am reading [Real Time UML: Advances in the UML for Real-Time Systems (3rd Edition) 3rd Edition
by Bruce Powel Douglass](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321160762)

In section 10.5 when talking about guidlines on detailed design on visibility. he says:

**Only make semantically appropriate operations visible.**

> This guideline
> seeks to avoid pathological coupling among classes. For example,
> suppose a class is using a container class. Should the operations be
> GetLeft() and GetRight() or Prev() and Next()? The first pair makes
> the implementation visible (binary tree) while the latter pair
> captures the essential semantics (ordered list).

I am unable to understand what he is trying to say here and especially last line.

Can someone elaborate his point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a bit subtile. `GetLeft` and `-Right` have the directions in their name which are derived from an internal implementation as binary tree. So the internal data structure is sort of visible in the interface. And that should not be the case. It is better to keep this knowledge inside for several reasons. First, the outer world must not care how things are implemented. Second, if you decide to implement it in a different way (e.g. via a ring buffer) the `GetRight` would be odd from an internal view if you reach the right border of the buffer. `Prev` and `Next` clearly target the business/outer usage aspect of the operations.